# Generated WCF proxy configuration uses server's local name

Tags: c#, wcf, local, svcutil.exe, endpoint

We have a service hosted behind our firewall that receives request forwarded through to it by the external router. The service is working fine, however whenever one of our clients adds a service reference using svcutil or Visual Studio, the generated app.config file always contains the endpoint address as https://myserver.myinternaldomain/... rather than https://secure.myexternaldomain.com/... which obviously isn't accessible to the outside world.

I've been playing with the config for ages now and I just can't get it to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have 3 options:

1. Change the config of your website in IIS to add a host header value of "secure.myexternaldomain.com".
2. In your `<endpoint>` elements in your WCF configuration, specify the complete address of the service (i.e. including the domain).
3. Use the [`<baseAddresses>`](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2006/07/13/31879.aspx) configuration element.

Comment: Number one for me as well.  I tried 2 and 3, but no joy.  Thanks.